# How to unbind/off jQuery event when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window

I am trying to delete a jquery event when the window gets >490. However, the unblind() or off() elements do not deactivate the action activated when the window gets smaller than 490px. Why is this? Does anyone knows any method to make a selection return to its original state?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width()<490) {
    $("#shown").unbind().click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("body div hidden").toggle('slow');
    });
    }

    else if ($(window).widht()>=490) {
        $("#shown").unbind();
        $("body div hidden").unbind();
    }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: It would be much easier to check the window size in the click event itself than to bind/unbind event handlers all the time. Also, you could achieve this with CSS alone using a media query and `pointer-events: none`

Comment: `hidden` selector looks suspicious. I guess it is a class or pseudo selector `:hidden`, not an element type. Anyway, ypu have better to follow Rory's advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve your desired, the below code will unbind the hide event based on the screen size.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
var eventPresent = false;
$(window).resize(function()
{
 console.log("current width : ", $(window).width());
 
if ($(window).width()<490 && eventPresent == false) 
{ 
 $("#shown").unbind().click(function(event)
 {
   event.preventDefault();   
   $("#divText").toggle('hide');
 });
 eventPresent  = true;
}    
else if ($(window).width()>=490 && eventPresent == true) 
{            
   $("#shown").unbind();
   $("#divText").show()  
   eventPresent = false;     
 }
  });
});
```

```html
 <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <a id="shown">click me to hide text</a>
   
<div id="divText">
                
You can not toggle me if screen is more than 490 px wide
         
</div>
```

P.S Run the snippet in full page mode.

Comment: This looks to work amazingly. Although it looks like it does not work for the option of toggling. You see, the thing to hide is a menu, I want the user to see the other options when clicking on the "shown". At the moment when I click the 'shown' disappears but does not reappears.

I would also ask you what the var, the console.log and the eventPresent true/false do, but maybe that'd be a lesson, for the moment I compliment myself for your skills in coding!

Comment: It works fine for toggle as well, i have updated the code for the same. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: glad that it was useful :).